# Trying to get PyCharm to work, keep getting "No Python interpreter selected"

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to learn Python and decided to use PyCharm.  When I try to start a new project I get a dialog that says "No Python interpreter selected".  It has a drop down to select a interpreter, but the drop down is empty.

Comment: Do you have Python installed? If not, there's your problem.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224357/executable-not-specified-error-in-pycharm

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your problem probably is that you haven't *installed* python. Meaning that, if you are using Windows, you have not downloaded the installer for Windows, that you can find on the official Python website.

In case you have, chances are that PyCharm cannot find your Python installation because its not in the default location, which is usually `C:\Python27` or `C:\Python33` (for me at least).

So, if you *have* installed Python and it still gives this error, then there can be two things that have happened:

1. You use a `virtualenv` and that `virtualenv` has been deleted or the filepath changed. In this case, you will have to find proceed to the next part of this answer.
2. Your python installation is not in its default place, in which case you will need to find its location, and locate the `python.exe` file.

Once you have located the necessary binaries, you will need to tell PyCharm were to look:

1. Open your settings dialogue <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Then you will need to type in `interpreter` in the search box:

   [image]
3. As you can see above, you will need to go to `Project Interpreter` and then go to `Python Interpreter`. The location has been selected for you in the above image.
4. To the side you will see a couple of options as icons, click the big `+` icon, then click on `local`, because your interpreter is on *this* computer.
5. This will open up a dialogue box. Make sure to select the `python.exe` file of that directory, do not give pycharm the whole directory. It just wants the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just wanted to say that the user have to `hide the taskbar on windows` in order to see the `ok` button :)

Comment: No `virtualenv` here, and python is installed to the default location as well.  Still had this issue.  The answer here helped get me to the point to where it was working, however I had to restart pycharm to make the changes for some odd reason.

Comment: This did not work with Ubuntu 16.04, PyCharm edition 2017.2.1. There isn't even "Python Interpreters" under "Project Interpreter" as depicted in the screenshot.

Comment: At first I chuckled and thought "noob mistake by OP! ha!"....and then I realized that was exactly my problem ^_^!  Time to install...

Comment: This same solution worked on Ubuntu too. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: NOTE: Please restart PyCharm after this if you still see the "No Python Interpreter selected" message in your Python Console.

Answer (score 24):

Go to `File->Settings->Project Settings->Project Interpreter->Python Interpreters`

There will be a "+" sign on the right side. Navigate to your python binary, PyCharm will figure out the rest.

Comment: Thank you for answering my quastion, by python binary, is that the PyCharm image file??

Comment: @Tedpottel `python` binary is what you are using to run your Python scripts, like `d:\dev\Python27\python.exe` on Windows or `/usr/bin/python` on Mac/Linux.

Comment: This was the easiest answer. Works well!

Answer (score 4):

This situation occurred to me when I uninstalled a method and tried to reinstall it. My very same interpreter, which worked before, suddenly stopped working. And this error occurred.

I tried restarting my PC, reinstalling Pycharm, invalidating caches, nothing worked.

Then I went here to reinstall the interpreter:
https://www.python.org/downloads/

When you install it, there's an option to fix the python.exe interpreter. Click that. My IDE went back to normal working conditions.

Answer (score 3):

During the install of python make sure you have "Install for all users" selected.
Uninstall python and do a custom install and check "Install for all users".

Answer (score 3):

for mac I can tell you that first you have to check your path

by executing this command

`which python` or `which python3`

[image: check where python is installed]

then you have to configure it in your pycharm.

**pycharm-->preferences-->gear button-->add..**

[image]

click on **system interpreter**--> then on **...**

then you search where your python version is installed

[image]

once it is done then you have to configure for your project

click on edit configuration

[image]

then choose the **python interpreter**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I has to close PyCharm, delete the .idea folder then open PyCharm again.

Answer (score 1):

Even I got the same issue and my mistake was that I didn't download python MSI file. You will get it here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Once you download the msi, run the setup and that will solve the problem. After that you can go to File->Settings->Project Settings->Project Interpreter->Python Interpreters

and select the python.exe file. (This file will be available at c:\Python34)
Select the python.exe file. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu, Python has already been downloaded on your PC.
so, go to -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> -> search `interpreter` -> go to `project interpreter` than select `Python 3.6` in the dropdown menu.

**Edit:** If there is no Python interpreter in drop-down menu, you should click the gear icon that on the right of the drop-down menu --> `add` --> select an `interpreter`.

(on PyCharm 2018.2.4 Community Edition)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when i newly installed pycharm in my windows 10 machine.

- download python setup
- install this solved my problem.

for more help [visit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-7-hXDkRvs&feature=youtu.be)
goodluck

> During the install of python make sure you have "Install for all users" selected. Uninstall python and do a custom install and check "Install for all users"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there are several interpreters, but I have to manually add them.

To the right of where you see "No Interpreters", there is a gear icon. Click the gear icon -> Click "Add...", then you can add the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Python Interpreter installed on your machine whereas Pycharm is looking for a Python interpreter, just go to https://www.python.org/downloads/
and download python and then create a new project, you'll be all set!

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, it was solved by opening PyCharm from the terminal and leaving it open. After that, I was able to choose the correct interpreter in preferences. In my case, linked to a virtual environment (venv).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and stumbled onto this solution.
I ran PyCharm (as administrator, though not sure if necessary).
After PyCharm has completely loaded (green tick mark top right), see  bottom right. Click on it.
An interface will open. In my case the path was already there. I just clicked OK and all was fine.
closed PyCharm and ran it again normally. Still all fine.

Comment: Sorry - That must be "See  <no iiterpreter> bottom right"

Answer (score 0):

What happened in my case was that I moved my project from one folder to another. My old `venv` was not being read correctly because in the `activate` file under `venv/bin/activate/` the `VIRTUAL_ENV` path was quite different. So edit that path and pycharm will let you add the interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything others wrote here, no success.

Then I have completely deleted everything and tried to start from scratch, as follows.

- Uninstalled all python installations
- Uninstalled all Pycharm installations
- Removed all .venv directories from all projects
- Removed all .idea directories from all projects
- Removed all directories under $HOME/.virtualenvs
- Removed all directories under $USER/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains

Then in the next steps, I have tried to reinstall everything as follows.

- Installed a single python interpreter (python 3.12 amd64)
- As administrator, upgraded pip (python -m pip install pip --upgrade)
- As administrator, installed pipenv (python -m pip install pipenv --upgrade)
- Created an empty .venv in my projects's directory, removed Pipenv.lock and ran "pipenv install" - that succeeded
- Reinstalled PyCharm, started and chose not to import any options
- After that, I added a system interpreter to PyCharm, **and waited until it reindexed the whole thing, including the SDK**
- Then exited pycharm
- Then started up pycharm again, opened the project directory
- Went to projects settings / python interpreter again, and added "existing virtualenv interpreter", located the interpreter under project_dir/.venv/Scripts/python.exe

And then I got this error:

```
Cannot set up a python SDK at Python 3.13 (project_name) (C:\Prog\Python\project_name\.venv\Scripts\python.exe). The SDK seems invalid.
```

The strangest thing is that I don't even have Python 3.13 installed, **and I never had**. I only have Python 3.12. Where is this 3.13 coming from?

Then restarted the whole procedure from the beginning, with these small changes:

- After deleting the python installation, I have manually deleted the remaining Program Files/Python* directory.
- I did not upgrade pip.
- Installed pipenv with "pip install pipenv" instead of "pip install pipenv --upgrade"

This time it worked. It might be something with the upgraded pip or pipenv, but I'm not sure. I was not able to determine the exact cause, but the above steps fixed it.