# "executable not specified" error in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

When I try to run a python script in PyCharm, I get this error message:

> `error running myscript: Executable is not specified`

and the script does not run. How do I run my script through PyCharm?

Comment: See here for setting a default project interpreter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679150/how-to-set-default-pycharm-interpreter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to designate an interpreter for the project.

`File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter`, and then select an interpreter at the right.

It looks like this on PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.3:

[image: File -> Settings]

[image: Project -> Project Interpreter -> Select Interpreter]

The official JetBrains guide to setting up an interpreter can be found [here.](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html)