# Why can i not import sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why am I not able to import sklearn?
I downloaded Anaconda Navigator and it has scikit-learn in it. I even pip installed sklearn , numpy and scipy in Command Prompt and it shows that it has already been installed, but still when I import sklearn in Python (I use PyCharm for coding) it doesn't work. It says 'No module named sklearn'.

Comment: What happens if you import it via terminal by activating your anaconda ?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224357/executable-not-specified-error-in-pycharm/28224358#28224358    Make sure PyCharm is pointing at the Anaconda installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your python interpretor in pycharm is probably not pointing to Anaconda's python, but to the system's default.

See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) to select the correct python binary.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I didn't know that I was supposed to change my interpreter to Anaconda's interpreter(I am fairly new to Python). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is working with via bash here are the steps :

**For ubunutu :**

> sudo apt-get install python-sklearn