# PyCharm doesn't identify 'import random' (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.8

I was working on my discord bot when PyCharm suddenly didn't identify `random`. If is relevant, I uninstalled official python to free up some space on my computer.

Code (?):

```
import random
```

Comment: this is PyCharm 2020.3.2, installed earlier today, just noting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have an official python version installed to use python according to this [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/quick-start-guide.html#interpreter). To help you understand this is basically trying to put on whipped cream to a cake but the whipped cream doesn't exist.

If you install a new version of python than previously:

[image] Press `Ctrl+Alt+S` Go down to where it says `Project:` then select Python Interpreter.

[image]

Click the cog -> show all. Remove the ones that don't exist. Then select add then select the Base interpreter from the installation. You want to select `python.exe`

Comment: Yes, I downloaded Python, but I realised that I now have Python 3.9 and PyCharm is on 3.8 How do I fix this?

Comment: Am I supposed to download Python 3.8?

Comment: (https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/696352490437738516/800301324200837160/unknown.png) It says that it is invalid

Comment: @235baron follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645527/trying-to-get-pycharm-to-work-keep-getting-no-python-interpreter-selected