# Error:Python interpreter is not selected. Please setup Python interpreter first

Tags: python, pycharm

I really don't know what's wrong. One second, my file for my mobile app is working, then I resolved a conflict and PyCharm goes haywire. This is the error I see when I try to open the python console:

```
Error:Python interpreter is not selected. Please setup Python interpreter first.
```

I currently have the latest version of **PyCharm 2021.1.3**. I tried to delete and redownload PyCharm but when I did, it didn't work, so I deleted my `venv` to reconfigure my environment but that was dumb because it's not allowing me to create a new interpreter. There are none there.

Also, I know this was an issue for a lot of people in the past but PyCharm's IDE has really changed since so all the past solutions aren't working, for instance I tried everything from this thread: [Trying to get PyCharm to work, keep getting "No Python interpreter selected"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19645527/15232838) and several others.

Here is a picture of how my PyCharm and Settings look:

[image]

I've never had IDE problems till now.

**Solution**

I followed the directions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68203363) and it worked. All I had to do was start a new project but with my original file and existing sources.

Comment: You have a clear error: SELECT a python interpret (no need to delete venv or reinstall pycharm). Click on that message, and you get where you need to select the env. Probably the source contain also some pycharm configuration, which select a environment which works on a different users (so tell your team to crarefully choose what to insert in a commit)

Comment: I know how to configure the interpreter regularly, this issue seems to be a bit different. Also, I can't click on the message. I updated my question with an image of my PyCharm and Settings so you can understand what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: I actually already have a link to that link in my question and it's a bit outdated. I believe the answers may be synonymous to my solution but PyCharm's IDE has changed quite a bit since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Project: [Your project name] -> Python Interpreter.

Then:

Select the Python interpreter you wish to use from the drop-down menu.

-- OR --

Press the cog button to add a new interpreter, which you may need to do if you have deleted yours! You just need to have the "New environment" radio button selected, choose a location for the virtual environment and select a base interpreter.

Comment: I know this is the regular way to configure your interpreter but I can't do that, because 1) it's not showing my project in settings, and 2) even when I go straight to Python Interpreter it doesn't show any options. I'm pretty sure I have Python 3.8 in the right area too. I updated my question with a picture of PyCharm and Settings so you can see how this looks.

Comment: @K-Dot then we'd need a screenshot of that (the one you included does show the right item expanded). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68203363) or try deleting the `.idea` folder in your project directory (make a backup) and try reopening the project.